# How to include Many to Many Field in SubFactory (Django)?

Tags: python, django, factory-boy

I have two models: `Project` and `Tag`. In `Project` there is ManyToManyField: `project_tags` I have written factories for both of them. The problem is that I don't know how to include `TagFactory` to `ProjectFactory`

I have tried:

```
project_tags = factory.SubFactory(TagFactory)
```

Error:

```
TypeError: Direct assignment to the forward side of a many-to-many set is prohibited. Use project_tags.set() instead
```

And also:

```
Project.project_tags.set()
```

Error:

```
AttributeError: 'ManyToManyDescriptor' object has no attribute 'set'
```

Comment: `project_tags = factory.project_tags.set(TagFactory object here)`
I'm not familiar with factory_boy at all, so :)

Comment: @Crosby not working but thanks ;)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The simple solution is through [`factory.RelatedFactory`](https://factoryboy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/reference.html#relatedfactory) or [`factory.RelatedFactoryList`](https://factoryboy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/reference.html#factory.RelatedFactoryList):

```py
class ProjectFactory(factory.django.DjangoModelFactory):
    class Meta:
        model = Project

    tags = factory.RelatedFactoryList(
        TagFactory,
        size=4,
    )
```